# Get all inherited classes of an abstract class

Tags: c#, reflection, inheritance

I have an abstract class:

```
abstract class AbstractDataExport
{
        public string name;
        public abstract bool ExportData();
}
```

I have classes which are derived from AbstractDataExport:

```
class XmlExport : AbstractDataExport
{
    new public string name = "XmlExporter";
    public override bool ExportData()
    {
        ...
    }
}
class CsvExport : AbstractDataExport
{
    new public string name = "CsvExporter";
    public override bool ExportData()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this? (Pseudocode:)

```
foreach (Implementation imp in Reflection.GetInheritedClasses(AbstractDataExport)
{
    AbstractDataExport derivedClass = Implementation.CallConstructor();
    Console.WriteLine(derivedClass.name)
}
```

with an output like

```
CsvExporter
XmlExporter
```

?

The idea behind this is to just create a new class which is derived from AbstractDataExport so i can iterate through all implementations automatically and add for example the names to a Dropdown-List.
I just want to code the derived class without changing anything else in the project, recompile, bingo!

If you have alternative solutions: tell em.

Thanks

Answer (score 232, accepted):

This is such a common problem, especially in GUI applications, that I'm surprised there isn't a BCL class to do this out of the box. Here's how I do it.

```
public static class ReflectiveEnumerator
{
    static ReflectiveEnumerator() { }

    public static IEnumerable<T> GetEnumerableOfType<T>(params object[] constructorArgs) where T : class, IComparable<T>
    {
        List<T> objects = new List<T>();
        foreach (Type type in 
            Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(T)).GetTypes()
            .Where(myType => myType.IsClass && !myType.IsAbstract && myType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T))))
        {
            objects.Add((T)Activator.CreateInstance(type, constructorArgs));
        }
        objects.Sort();
        return objects;
    }
}
```

A few notes:

- Don't worry about the "cost" of this operation - you're only going to be doing it once (hopefully) and even then it's not as slow as you'd think.
- You need to use `Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(T))` because your base class might be in a different assembly.
- You need to use the criteria `type.IsClass` and `!type.IsAbstract` because it'll throw an exception if you try to instantiate an interface or abstract class.
- I like forcing the enumerated classes to implement `IComparable` so that they can be sorted.
- Your child classes must have identical constructor signatures, otherwise it'll throw an exception. This typically isn't a problem for me.

Comment: Can a type be not-abstract and non-class at the same time?

Comment: This is absolutely insane! I had no idea you could do stuff like this with reflection.

Comment: @user2341923 an enum?

Comment: What if the sub-class could be defined in a different assembly?

Comment: @tobriand This will search all assemblies: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes()).Where(....

Comment: I've used that a couple of times in the last few years... does sometimes catch me out though when there's a reference that's managed to creep through without some of its dependencies. But yes, it grabs subtypes :). Worth noting that `GetAssemblies()` get's the *loaded* assemblies, not the *referenced* ones, from memory. This can sometimes be a pain.

Comment: How do I bookmark this!!!

Answer (score 83):

Assuming they are all defined in the same assembly, you can do:

```
IEnumerable<AbstractDataExport> exporters = typeof(AbstractDataExport)
    .Assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AbstractDataExport)) && !t.IsAbstract)
    .Select(t => (AbstractDataExport)Activator.CreateInstance(t));
```

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. Need to take a closer look on `Activator.CreateInstance`

Comment: Use `t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null` as an additional constraint to prevent trying to instantiate classes that don't have a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 13):

It may not be the elegant way but you can iterate all classes in  the assembly and invoke  `Type.IsSubclassOf(AbstractDataExport)`
 for each one.

Comment: +1: I believe that's pretty much the only solution.

Comment: Thank you very much! My solution is based on your suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

`typeof(AbstractDataExport).Assembly` tells you an assembly your types are located in (assuming all are in the same).

`assembly.GetTypes()` gives you all types in that assembly or `assembly.GetExportedTypes()` gives you types that are public.

Iterating through the types and using `type.IsAssignableFrom()` gives you whether the type is derived.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, assembly.gettypes() was something i needed for the solution.