# How to dynamically obtain non-generic types and properties for a class?

Tags: c#, reflection

How to dynamically obtain **all non-generic** classes that inherit from the Person class (Student, Teacher) and properties (Address) for the Person class.

Example code:

```
 [DataContract]
 [KnownType(typeof(Student))]
 [KnownType(typeof(Teacher))]
 public abstract class Person {
     [DataMember]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     [DataMember]
     public string Surname { get; set; }

     [DataMember]
     public Address _Address { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Do you mean other non-generic classes that inherit from Person? Or do you mean all non-generic properties of the Person class?

Comment: I mean both non-generic classes that inherit from the Person class and all non-generic properties :)

Comment: Look at this Thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411694/get-all-inherited-classes-of-an-abstract-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To look for all classes that inherit Person, you need to define where you are looking. You can't look everywhere. Suppose that all classes are in the same assembly as the Person class you can write that:

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Person)).GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(Person).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.ContainsGenericParameters);
```

As for the properties, do the same in a foreach loop on all properties:

```
foreach (var pi in typeof(Person).GetProperties())
{
// Do the same for pi.PropertyType
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var nonGenericProperties = typeof(Person)
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(p => !p.IsGenericType)
    .ToList();

var nonGenericClassesWhichInheritFromPerson = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Person))
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Person))
    .ToList()
```

The second query only checks for derived types in the same assembly.

Comment: I think that your IsAssignableFrom is not correct http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110)

Comment: IsSubclassOf is also an option, maybe better since this won't return the person itself.