# Get all types that derive from a certain class in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

There are a few posts on here regarding how to find all derived classes from a given class programatically ([Get all inherited classes of an abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411694/get-all-inherited-classes-of-an-abstract-class)), but none that I can see when using Visual Studio (2015).

I'm looking at the 'Object Browser' window and I'm surprised such a feature doesn't exist. Am I doing something wrong or is there really no way to find out?

Comment: I have ReSharper installed so the menu item may be from that tool but if you right-click the class name (I did it in the source code editor), do you have a "Go to implementation" menu item there? Does it give you a popup of the descendants?

Comment: The Class Diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. Visual Studio doesn't support that.

There are some third party tools that can do this for you:

- JetBrains Resharper
- Redgate Reflector