# What is the type of element (of a collection) which retrieve from using Activator.CreateInstance method?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, createinstance, fieldinfo

I have a case which is very similar to the case below：

[Get all inherited classes of an abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411694/get-all-inherited-classes-of-an-abstract-class)

I have two classes which inherited to a base class

this is my base class:

```
public abstract class InputModule
{
      public string ModuleName;
      public int NumberOfInputFields;
}
```

And this is the first inhertied class:

```
public class Module1 : InputModule
{
      new public string  ModuleName = "FilmMusic";
      public new int NumberOfInputFields = 7;
}
```

second:

```
public class Module2 : InputModule
{
      new public string ModuleName = "MovieStaffInfo";
      public new int NumberOfInputFields = 4;
}
```

And I want to get the value of ModuleName: "FilmMusic" and "MovieStaffInfo".

With the value, before user entering the main form, I could add a new UI (UI for FilmMusic Module and another UI for MovieStaff) to the main form.

And below were the codes I have used (most referred to the case I have mentioned above):

```
public void detectTotalNumberOfSector()
{
     IEnumerable<InputModule> exporters = typeof(InputModule).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(InputModule)) && !t.IsAbstract).Select(t => (InputModule)Activator.CreateInstance(t));
     foreach (var item in exporters)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(item.ModuleName);   
     } 
}
```

And I got the output "null, null"

And I added those codes inside the foreach loop:

```
FieldInfo info = item.GetType().GetField("ModuleName"); 
Console.WriteLine(info.GetValue(item));
```

I have got what I want "FilmMusic, MovieStaffInfo".

I am a little bit confuse, what the elements inside the exporters collection ?

At first, I guess the `item` is an instantiation of class `Module1`, `Module2`...,therefore I could use `item.ModuleName` to access the value of `ModuleName`.

Actually, I can't, I have to use `FieldInfo` and `GetValue` to access the field value, but it is also strange, because using `GetValue` I have to create an instantiation first as a parameter assign to `GetValue` (in my case, the `item` is an instantiation of class `Module1`,`Module2`... I guess).

So, are the items of the collection exporters an instantiation of class Module1, Module2 or not?

If they are, why I got null when using `item.ModuleName` ?

Thanks for any opinion~

Comment: Why do you think you need a the `new` modifier for your fields? I am pretty sure they cause the trouble here.

Comment: I have tried remove the `new` from `new public string  ModuleName = "FilmMusic"` and `new public string ModuleName = "MovieStaffInfo`; but I still got null when output.

Comment: That still hides the original member in the base class. Set your values using the constructor. Redeclaring the field means there are two complete independant fields now: `InputModule.ModuleName` and `Module1.ModuleName`.

Comment: Thanks to the explanation, it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined `ModuleName` with the `new` keyword (e.g. `new public string ModuleName`). This means that if the variable pointing at the instance is typed as the base class, it won't be able to see the "new" field.

If you want to be able to see the module names, you have two options.

1. Get rid of the `new` keyword. Instead, declare the member as an override, e.g.

   ```
   public override string ModuleName = "etc.";
   ```
2. Use reflection to invoke the field on the derived type, e.g.

   ```
   Console.WriteLine
   (
       item.GetType()
           .GetField("ModuleName", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
           .GetValue(item)
   );
   ```

See also [Difference between new and overrride](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399127/difference-between-new-and-override)

Personally I recommend the first option. It is unusual to need the `new` keyword.

Comment: Not redeclaring the field and just set its value in the constructor is also an option.

Comment: Thanks, I see. The `item` indeed is an instance of Module1, Module2... Therefore I could use `item` to get the value of field `ModuleName` by `GetValue`. The reason that I got null when using `item.ModuleName`, because it refers to the ModuleName of base class, and the value is null.