# How to Get List of Simple Inherited Types?

Tags: c#, types

I have a mother class that wants to list inherited classes. Shows nothing when using `GetNestedTypes`.

```cs
public class Animal { }

public class Dog : Animal { }
public class Cat : Animal { }
public class Bird : Animal { }
```

Below a hypothetical code, I'm looking for a method like the one below that can provide me with this list. What should I use?

```cs
public void Start()
{
    List<Type> inheritedTypes = typeof(Animal).GetInheritedTypes(); // I need some method like this..

    inheritedTypes.ForEach(T => Debug.Log(typeof(T).Name)); // show Dog, Cat, Bird
}
```

Comment: Does this help? [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411694/get-all-inherited-classes-of-an-abstract-class)

Comment: @LiadDadon thank u for response, duplicate link helps. <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for an extension method

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
  public static class MyExtensions
  {
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetInheritedTypes(this Type BaseClass) 
    {
      
        IEnumerable<Type> subclassTypes = Assembly
         .GetAssembly(BaseClass)
         .GetTypes()
         .Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(BaseClass));
        return subclassTypes;
    }
  }
}
```

Don't forget you need some reflection here (using System.Reflection;)

And then you can use it like you want:
-include the extension method where you need it (using ExtensionMethods;)
and invoke it:

```
var listofChildTypes = typeof(Animal).GetInheritedTypes();
```

Comment: I read Jon Skeet's answer that solved the problem in duplicate post, but this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much, it solved the problem completely and is much easier.